# What's the meaning of new and curly brace (without type to create)?

Tags: scala, saddle

I found the following definition in Scala Saddle and just want to be sure I understood it correctly. There is an object defining an implicit function that exposes some HDF5 I/O functionality to the Frame type so that the `writeHdfFile` function becomes available to any Frame:

```
object H5Implicits {
  /**
   * Provides enrichment on Frame object for writing to an HDF5 file.
   */
  implicit def frame2H5Writer[RX: ST: ORD, CX: ST: ORD, T: ST](frame: Frame[RX, CX, T]) = new {

    /**
     * Write a frame in HDF5 format to a file at the path provided
     *
     * @param path File to write
     * @param id Name of the HDF group in which to store frame data
     */
    def writeHdfFile(path: String, id: String) {
      H5Store.writeFrame(path, id, frame)
    }

  } // end new
}
```

However, I have never seen the `= new {` syntax before. Does it mean it is creating and returning a new function each time? why would that make more sense as opposed to simply doing `= {`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a new anonymous class with 1 function.

In this case its used to provide syntax to the `frame: Frame[RX, CX, T]`.

With this helper class in scope you can write.

```
frame.writeHdfFile(...)
```

Without this technique you would need to write.

```
writeHdfFile(frame, ...)
```

Normally this is done with a implicit class rather than a implicit def like that.

One benefit of this technique is that you can add helper methods to a class without changing them directly. Note how `writeHdfFile` is not defined on `Frame`

This is done pretty similar to how type classes are implemented in scala.

Answer (score 2):

it is creating an anonymous class. You can learn more about [anonymous classes in scala here](https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/133.html)